# Ruby Mechanize Gem find fields without names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize, scrape

I’m trying to use the mechanize gem to scrape a page that is behind a login. However for the site i am using, they don’t name their username or password fields in the html. I’ve searched the Mechanize documentation, but i cannot fins the code to enter textin a field without using the field name. Is there a way to find the 5th element on the page, or the first text box?

Comment: if it doesn't have a name, then nothing gets submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
agent = Mechanize.new 
page = agent.get(<yourpage>)
form = page.forms[<index of form>]
form.fields[<index of field>].value = '<your value>'  # setting the values
form.fields[<index of field2>].value = '<your value2>'# setting the values
page2 = form.submit                                   # submitting the form
```

Comment: How do I assign value to this? Previously I would have main.email = 'email@email.com'

Comment: @user1895399 this did not help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have liberty to use other gem then why don't you try using [Nokogiri Gem.](http://www.nokogiri.org/)

It is very flexible where you can use either css selector OR can use XPath selector to [search specific elements](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html).